# Ordinary Differential Equations in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Question -

I am working on some matlab code that solves 2 first degree differentials and 2 second order differentials. I am ok with dsolve() but when I want to plot I am currently using ezplot and it is not giving me what I want. I want to produce 1 window with four graphs. I know I would use subplot but I dont know how, an example would be nice. Also I dont know how to make my plots show the importiant area not just a large area. my code is below:

```
close all  % close all figure windows that are open
clear all  % clear all the variables currently stored in memory
clc        % clear the commands in the command window

%%Problem 1%%%%%
a = (dsolve('Dv = -500*v+5000','v(0)=5'));
display (a)
b = (dsolve('Dx = -2000*x+100','x(0)=-.02'));
display (b)

%%Problem 2%%%%%
c = (dsolve('D2y+2000*Dy+26000000*y-520000000=0','Dy(0)=0','y(0)=5'));
display(c)
d = (dsolve('D2y+100*Dy+2500*y-520000000=0','Dy(0)=20','y(0)=0'));
display (d)

figure
ezplot(a);
axis([0,.01,4,10])

figure
ezplot(b);
axis([0,.01,0,10])

figure
ezplot(c);
axis([0,.01,4,10])

figure
ezplot(d);
axis([0,.01,4,10])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know until now, but it seems that `ezplot` only generates data points for "interesting part" of your plot. So if you specify the x-limit that `ezplot` does not use, you don't see anything. What you need to do is to specify the x-limits in its second argument of `ezplot`. Then, you can create subplots with standard `suplot` function, get axis handle, and specify the axis. The plotting part of your code should be like this.

```
figure
h1=subplot(2,2,1);
ezplot(a, [0,0.01]);
axis(h1,[0,0.01,4,10])

h2=subplot(2,2,2);
ezplot(b, [0,0.01]);
axis(h2,[0,.01,0,10])

h3=subplot(2,2,3);
ezplot(c, [0,0.01]);
axis(h3,[0,.01,4,10])

h4=subplot(2,2,4);
ezplot(d, [0,0.01]);
axis(h4,[0,.01,4,10])
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, I actually need to zoom in on these "interesting parts" but I have a good idea what to do. thanks for your help

Comment: UPDATE: I began trying to change the axis values as mentioned above and I remembered the command axis tight; this solved the 'interesting' portion of the graph problem.